# Ansible conditionally delegate_to local or remote?

Tags: ansible

I have a few `ansible` playbooks which sometimes make sense in the local context, otherwise they are executed remotely. In order to do that I use `delegate_to` directive, but that also means that I have to double all my tasks, eg.:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Local command
    command: hostname
    register: target_host
    when: vhost is undefined
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

# ---    

  - name: Remote command
    command: hostname
    register: target_host
    when: vhost is defined
```

***Exec locally***:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inv.d/test.ini play.d/delegate.yml

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

TASK: [Local command] ********************************************************* 
changed: [new-server -> 127.0.0.1]

TASK: [Remote command] ******************************************************** 
skipping: [new-server]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
new-server                 : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

***Exec on remote***:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inv.d/test.ini play.d/delegate.yml -e vhost=y

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

TASK: [Local command] ********************************************************* 
skipping: [new-server]

TASK: [Remote command] ******************************************************** 
changed: [new-server]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
new-server                 : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Is there a smarter way to tell `ansible` when to fallback to the local environment? Currently I'm using `ansible==1.9.2`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where tasks should be executed should not be defined in the tasks. Delegation makes sense when tasks always have to be run locally or on a related machine (e.g. database host or router) while the playbook itself and therefore most of the tasks run the hosts defined on playbook level.

But if your goal is to run the whole playbook either locally or on a set of remote hosts, you should work with different inventory files or groups.

If you have two different inventory files, in one you define localhost, in the other all the remote hosts, then apply the inventory you want when calling ansible, `-i inv.d/local` or `-i inv.d/remote`.

Or have it all in one inventory and dynamically pass the group. In your inventory you define two groups:

```
[local]
127.0.0.1

[remote]
host-1
host-2
host-N
```

And then pass the group as an extra-var to ansible: `-e "run=local"` or `-e "run=remote"`

In your playbook you set the `hosts` dynamically:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ run | mandatory }}"
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    ...
```

In your example it appears you only work with a single remote host defined per `vhost` extra-var. In that case the best option appears to be to re-use this variable in the hosts section and default to localhost.

```
---
- hosts: "{{ vhost | default('127.0.0.1') }}"
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    ...
```

So if `vhost` is defined the whole playbook will be executed on that host. If it is not defined the playbook runs locally.

Finally, you still could use the `delegate_to` option on single tasks like so:

```
- name: Local AND remote command
  command: hostname
  delegate_to: "{{ '127.0.0.1' if vhost is undefined else omit }}"
```

[`omit` is a special variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-undefined-variables-and-parameters) to make Ansible ignore the option, as if it would not have been defined.

Comment: Would it work: `connection: "{{ 'ansible_host' | default('local') }}"`? [Docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#non-ssh-connection-types) seem ambiguous, `ansible_host` is defined as the `name of the Docker container to connect to`. I'm willing that is just an error in the docs.

Comment: I would set the connection in the inventory file, like described at the bottom of this section: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups

Comment: `localhost              ansible_connection=local`

Comment: Actually I believe what I need is this: `connection: "{{ omit | default('local') }}"`

Comment: Just set it as a host var. `connection` is a behavioral parameter and does not need to be applied to the playbook or task. Once defined in the inventory or host-vars ansible will pick the correct connection type based on the host it connects to. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters

Comment: delegate_to expects an inventory host name.

From your inventory, oldserver is a group name that can potentially hold several host names.

A quick and dirty fix if you are sure that your group will always contain a single host is to use the first one in the list inside the group. So in this case you could delegate_to:  "{{ groups['oldserver'][0] }}"

Comment: @JithinKumarS Replied to the wrong post? There is no mention of any `oldserver` in the question nor answer.

Comment: old server I mean like whichever the host u are intended to.